# StarUML: go from Model Explorer to Design Model

Tags: staruml

All
Could you please suggest how can I move cursor from element on Model Explorer to it location on Design Model ?
I found that backward movement (Design Model -> Model Explorer) can be achieved by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to right click and select "Find in diagram" or "Find in model explorer", or something like it.